# Directive Angularjs, $watch and HTML Element

Tags: html, angularjs, element, directive, watch

I have a question. I coded a HTML page with an angularjs directive
this is my code

```
<menufileupload visible="rightVisible" alignment="right">
    <input type="text" ng-model='expr'/>    
    <!--Other stuff-->
</menufileupload>
```

I'm trying to use a $watch to check any change in the text field
$scope.$watch(...) only worked when the text field  is out of the
directive. So I think that I have to create a $watch in the directive. I did that. But it didn't work.

Directive

```
app.directive("menufileupload", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<div>bla</div>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('expr', function(obj) {
        alert("it changed");
      }, true);
    }
  };
});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It might be more helpful if you gave us a higher level view of the problem you need solved. I think you might be down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a template in your directive, so everything inside it will be replaced by that `<div>` tag.

It works fine if you remove the template. I made a codepen example of your code:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/jEzQVJ

```
angular.module('test', [])

.directive('menufileupload', function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('expr', function(obj) {
        alert("it changed");
      }, true);
    }
  };
});
```

If you want your input element to be shown inside the directive DOM you should use the `ngTransclude` directive. Please check it out in the documentation.